# JFreeChart - How to show real-time on the X-Axis of a TimeSeries chart

Tags: java, real-time, jfreechart, timeserieschart

I want to show live data on a TimeSeries chart with **real time shown on the x-axis** (or at least have the speed of the time the same as real-time).

Here is a SSCCE of the problem with random numbers as the live input. The time shown on the x-axis is much faster than real-time (assuming it is shown in hh:mm:ss format):

```
public class DynamicTimeSeriesChart extends JPanel {

    private DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset;
    private JFreeChart chart = null;

    public DynamicTimeSeriesChart(final String title) {

        dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, 2000, new Second());
        dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1990)); // date 1st jan 0 mins 0 secs

        dataset.addSeries(new float[1], 0, title);
        chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            title, "Time", title, dataset, true,
            true, false);
        final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();

        ValueAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
        axis.setAutoRange(true);
        axis.setFixedAutoRange(200000); // proportional to scroll speed
        axis = plot.getRangeAxis();

        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(chartPanel);
    }

    public void update(float value) {
        float[] newData = new float[1];
        newData[0] = value;
        dataset.advanceTime();
        dataset.appendData(newData);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final DynamicTimeSeriesChart chart = new DynamicTimeSeriesChart("random numbers");
        frame.add(chart);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        chart.update((float) (Math.random() * 10));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While it is acceptable to `sleep()` on the [initial thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the event dispatch thread. Instead, use a `javax.swing.Timer` to pace the updates, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513). A `delay` of 100 ms will update at approximately 10 Hz.

If the drift is unacceptable, poll the host's clock from another thread at half the nominal rate and update the dataset using `EventQueue.invokeLater()`. Ensure that the host is synchronized to an NTP server.

Addendum: Based on your update, note that *all* Swing GUI objects must be constructed and manipulated *only* on the event dispatch thread, not just the [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). The advantage of a Swing `Timer` is that it fires on the EDT. The variation below shows 10 seconds of 1 Hz data at approximately real time.

Addendum: You can adjust the time passed to `setTimeBase()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31902373/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21307289/230513
 */
public class DynamicTimeSeriesChart extends JPanel {

    private final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset;
    private final JFreeChart chart;

    public DynamicTimeSeriesChart(final String title) {
        dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, 1000, new Second());
        dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 23, 1, 2014));
        dataset.addSeries(new float[1], 0, title);
        chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            title, "Time", title, dataset, true, true, false);
        final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        axis.setFixedAutoRange(10000);
        axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("ss.SS"));
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        add(chartPanel);
    }

    public void update(float value) {
        float[] newData = new float[1];
        newData[0] = value;
        dataset.advanceTime();
        dataset.appendData(newData);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                final DynamicTimeSeriesChart chart
                    = new DynamicTimeSeriesChart("Alternating data");
                frame.add(chart);
                frame.pack();
                Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    private boolean b;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        chart.update(b ? 1 : 0);
                        b = !b;
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed the SSCCE code to use what you suggested with the Timer and EventQueue.invokeLater(). The problem still remains though. I don't how to 'poll the host's clock' or 'ensure the host is synchronized to an NTP server'. I don't know how to set the time of the chart.

Comment: Comment to your addendum: Your example chart seems to show time at the speed of real-time, but when I change the rate of the Timer to anything other than 1 Hz, the chart shows time at a different speed. I want the chart to be able to show time at real speed regardless of the data update rate. Thanks for your efforts so far.

Comment: Real time is 1 Hz; you may be able to coalesce events arriving at a different rate.

Comment: I want the chart to be able to visually update at a higher rate than 1Hz and show time at real speed. Do you know how that could be done?

Comment: You may be able to get the desired effect using different tick units, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21277818/230513).

Comment: I tried changing the tick units using: 
`axis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.SECOND, 1));`
It didn't seem to change the speed of the time axis. It seems like whenever `advanceTime()` is called on a `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection` in your example, time goes forward 1 second. Maybe if I was able to change the amount of time that `advanceTime()` advanced time then that could be a solution to my problem.