# Real time graph plotting starting time

Tags: java, jfreechart

Here is code based on @trashgod's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21307289/230513) about real time plotting:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21307289/230513
 */
public class DynamicTimeSeriesChart extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5128935838291298041L;
private final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset;
private final JFreeChart chart;

public DynamicTimeSeriesChart(final String title) {
    dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, 1000, new Second());
    dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2014));
    dataset.addSeries(new float[1], 0, title);
    chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
        title, "Time", title, dataset, true, true, false);
    final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setFixedAutoRange(10000);
    axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("ss.SS"));
    final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    add(chartPanel);
}

public void update(float value) {
    float[] newData = new float[1];
    newData[0] = value;
    dataset.advanceTime();
    dataset.appendData(newData);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            final DynamicTimeSeriesChart chart
                = new DynamicTimeSeriesChart("Alternating data");
            frame.add(chart);
            frame.pack();
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                private boolean b;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    chart.update(b ? 1 : 0);
                    b = !b;
                }
            });
            timer.start();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

After running the Java, I still don't understand why the graph starts at 40 seconds, although the `new Seconds` start from 0? 
Ran through code; can't find any settings to start at 40 seconds.

Also, how to scroll back graph to see previous data.

Comment: Plus one for a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); I don't think scrolling is supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph starts at 16 minutes and 40 seconds after midnight on the date used to construct the `Second` passed to `setTimeBase()`. This is the same 1000 intervals, each one second long, specified in the `nMoments` constructor parameter. Some possible alternatives to get a zero-based display, given a time set to midnight.

1. Make `nMoments` a multiple of `60`.

   ```
   dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, 960, new Second());
   dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2014));
   ```
2. Subtract `nMoments` from the nominal base date.

   ```
   int nMoments = 1000;
   dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, nMoments, new Second());
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   c.setTime(new Date(0));
   c.add(Calendar.SECOND, -nMoments);
   dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(c.getTime()));
   ```

Either approach yields the same display.

[image]

Comment: It did work but i dont understand concept behind it :P would be great if u can explain it. Thanks for the solution! XD

Comment: I hav tried both solution but they still start from 16 (first solution) or 29 minutes (2nd solution).

Comment: lol i changed to 3600 and start from 00.00.... its desired but look unprofessional..

Comment: @HacXScedix: The alternative is to use `addValue()` to fill the initial `nMoments` slots, _then_ use `appendData()`; the details depend on your particular use case.