# JFreeChart - How to show real-time on the X-Axis of a TimeSeries chart and keep datas

Tags: java, real-time, jfreechart

I am new to JFreeChart.

I'd like to change [the code of Trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299096/jfreechart-how-to-show-real-time-on-the-x-axis-of-a-timeseries-chart) to monitor something in Java. So I need to:

1 - Keep all datas shown. His code keeps only the last 10 samples.

2 - Having a variable scale on X-axis :

- Having an int input howManyDays (or something like an int input, something a little bit clever would be great ;-) ) : int howManyDays = 7;//in this case : 1 week of datas
- Having a variable scale on X-axis a little bit complex : For example during the first seconds of execution it has for scale 1 minute. Then 10 minutes... When midnight has been passed, it should print the current day.

I know that this instruction

```
      Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener()
```

means that every 100 ms it adds a new data and then it updates the chart. I'll change it to 10 000 -> 10 seconds. My Timer for testing JFreeChart :

```
            Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
                private int i,data;
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if ((i%10)==0) {
                        this.data += (int) Math.ceil(2*Math.random());
                    }
                    this.i++;
                    chart.update(this.data);
                }
            });
```

Of course I don't need the solution.

What do I really need :

- Maybe if someone could add comment on Trashgod's code ?
- Or if someone could give me some tricks for doing this kind of code ?
- Or maybe someone has already done something like that ?

Have a good day !

Answer (score 1):

While your question is somewhat broad, here are some pointers to approaching such a task.

- `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection` is designed to retain only recent data, not all; note [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31932309/230513) how the time slots are filled.
- To keep all data, use a `TimeSeries` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6517440/230513); aged items will be removed only if you invoke `setMaximumItemAge()`.
- To format the time axis, use `setDateFormatOverride()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264230/230513); the tick units will adjust automatically as data accumulates; don't change them unless you have some some specific reason to do so.
- To collect data in the background, use a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try what you suggest

Comment: Well... I use a DB for my data... So I'll use a plugin of Eclipse : Birt

Comment: For having real-time on Eclipse click on Script then clientScripts. Then paste this script : [link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/163879/)

then run in external browser

Comment: First steps on birt : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23AZ7Hivzyg
                                                                     
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kpH3LYhmk4

Comment: It's for beginers  on birt (in this video the result at the end is a table but you can do charts as well with Birt) : 

you'll need to download your jdbc driver then update your datasource. then you can create your querry and finally update your layout